# Netezza SQL - How to replace string between two Comma's, with a condition

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a string where I want to find `:N` between two commas, and replace the data data between two commas with blank.  Example shown below.

Currently its being done manually with exporting it into excel, making changes and importing it back into database. I'm sure there would be a better way to have this done in coding without the need of export/import.

Example:

```
 "This is sting one:Y,this is string Two:X,This is string Three:N,This is string four:N,This is string five:X,"
```

Desired outcome:

```
"This is sting one:Y,this is string Two:X,This is string five:X,"
```

Would really appreciate your help.

A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [sql extensions toolkit](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_install_and_setup.html) and `regexp_replace`.

I've found that the nz implementation of regex seems to have some issues with the `?` non-greedy modifier on my version. The expression that worked here was `,[^(:N)]+:N`.

```
FORTUNE_DB(ADMIN)=> select * from so;
                                                     COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is sting one:Y,this is string Two:X,This is string Three:N,This is string four:N,This is string five:X,

FORTUNE_DB(ADMIN)=> select regexp_replace(col1,',[^(:N)]+:N','') from so;
                         REGEXP_REPLACE
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 This is sting one:Y,this is string Two:X,This is string five:X,
```

Comment: Since your first element might have `:N`, I'd probably change that regex at some point to be `(^|,)[^(:N)]+:N`

Comment: Thanks Jeremytwfortune.  I have tried using regexp_replace(Offers,'(^|,)[^(:N)]+:N','')  as Newoffer and it works just leaves a "," in the begenning. I guesss i can just use sub str to remove first comma if any.

Comment: I would suggest that the best thing to do would be to add one if one isn't found. That way you have an array where each element always starts with a comma.

Comment: Yup, either makes sense. Thanks for your help !